# Parity of permutation example

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I know the definition of parity of permutation. But what does that look like in examples? For example, if the number of permutations is odd, then the sign of permutation in $-1$. What does this mean? Can someone please give an example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you know the definition what exactly is the question?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I need some kind of an example. The book only gives the definition. I am confused

Comment: Ok. What is the notation for permutations that they use? There are two notations in common use, and using the one you may not be familiar with will make answering a bit difficult. Normally books first use table notation which looks like a matrix with two rows. A more efficient notation is the so called cycle notation, but I'm not sure if you know about that.

Comment: It uses cycle notation @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Great! Assuming that the definition of parity is in terms of *inverted pairs* (not 100% about the English terminology here), then can you verify that the permutation $(12)$ has only a single inverted pair, but the permutation $(123)$ has two?

Comment: Yeah, I understand that

Comment: Good. What about $(13)$? Or $(14)$? You can probably see that those have three and five inverted pairs respectively? Can you see that all 2-cycles are always odd?

Comment: Yes, that is clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example in $S_5$: let
$$\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\ 4&5&2&3&1\end{pmatrix}$$
The sign of $\sigma$ is the *parity of the number of inversions* when applying $\sigma$, i.e. the number of pairs $(i,\,j),\enspace i<j$ such that $\sigma(i)>\sigma(j)$.

Here we have:
\begin{align*}
\sigma(1) >{}&\sigma(3) &\sigma(2) >{}&\sigma(3)&\sigma(3) >{}&\sigma(5)\\
&\sigma(4) & &\sigma(4)&\sigma(4) >{}&\sigma(5)\\
&\sigma(5) & &\sigma(5)
\end{align*}
There are $8$ inversions, hence $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)=(-1)^ 8=1.$

Comment: I do not understand this. Why did you write $\sigma(3) >\sigma(5)$ twice?

Comment: Sorry, it was a bad copy-paste. It's corrected now.

Comment: So what does that $sgn(\sigma)=1$ imply? I do not get that

Comment: It just means $\sigma$  produces an even number of inversions, or that $\sigma$ is the product of an even number of transpositions. It's an invariant: whatever the number of transpositions $\sigma$ is made of, it will always be an even number. The signature is important because, among others things,it is involved in the computation of determinants.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to know that the parity of a transposition (i.e. a $2$-cycle) is always odd. The parity function $F : S_n \rightarrow (\{1,-1\}, \cdot)$ is a group homomorphism. Thus, if you know how to express any cycle as the product of transpositions, then you know the parity of any permutation.

Here's an example. Let $g = (1 \ 2)(3 \ 4 \ 5)(6 \ 7 \ 8 \ 9) \in S_9$. First you express $g$ as a product of transpositions. Now $(3 \ 4 \ 5) = (3 \ 5)(3 \ 4)$ and $(6 \ 7 \ 8 \ 9) = (6 \ 9)(6 \ 8)(6 \ 7)$ (see the general idea here?), hence $(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4 \ 5)(6 \ 7 \ 8 \ 9) = (1 \ 2)(3 \ 5)(3 \ 4)(6 \ 9)(6 \ 8)(6 \ 7)$. Thus $F(g) = (-1)^6 = 1$, as $F$ is a homomorphism (image of a product is the product of images).

In general, a cycle of length $n$ can be expressed as a product of $n-1$ transpositions. Thus a cycle of even length has odd parity ($(-1)^{n-1}$) and a cycle of odd length has even parity.