# find parity with inversion of permutation (14)(256)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

> For the permutation
>
> $$\pi= \begin{bmatrix} 1& 2& 3 &4& 5& 6 \\ 4 & 6& 3 & 1 & 2 & 5\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Find the number of inversions and parity.

---

$\pi=(14)(256)=(14)(25)(26)$. It is suppose to be odd.

Double check with [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) and  [bernard's  example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170611/parity-of-permutation-example)

Comment: You have an answer, so what's your question?

Comment: find inversions. and check $N(\pi)$ number of inversions $ sgn(\pi)=(-1)^{N(\pi)}=-1$. meaning it is odd.

Comment: All right, so how about you edit your question so that it's clear what you're asking?

Comment: Abstract algebra is a wide branch of mathematics, so whenever you post a question about it please include other tags like group/ring theory, cyclic subgroups/Ideals, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way to find the parity, by counting the **number of inversions**, i.e., the number of cases where we have simultaneously $i<j$ and $\pi(i)>\pi(j)$.

It is not sufficiently known that, for small length permutations, **this can be done graphically** by counting the number of intersections of the line segments joining, say, $(k,1)$ and $(\pi(k),0)$ as shown below for this example, where we find 9 intersections. The parity of this number, $(-1)^9=-1$, is the answer.

[image]